# D3D12 Convert DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM to DXGI_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM in GPU

Tags: video, directx, textures, encoder

I have a D3D12 Resource which is already in DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM

I need to D3D12 Convert DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM to DXGI_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM  in GPU
without using CPU for use in nvEncRegisterResource.

Comment: A compute shader would be Ideal for this

Answer (score 0):

create two textures one in DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM and other in DXGI_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM.
Then load them in to one shader for render to texture,
Then in shader write to second texture with RB values swapped to each other.